# How to fill a list based off of other items in the list in R?

Tags: r

I have a list that looks like this:

```
n <- c(1, rep(NA, 9), 2, rep(NA, 9))
```

I want the 9 observations following the first observation to contain the same value as the first observation.  And continue this pattern throughout the whole list.  So ideally, I want my list to look like this:

```
c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10))
```

I want to accomplish this without using for loops, is there a way to do this?

Comment: That isn't a `list`, it's a `vector`.  See `?list`

Answer (score 5):

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(n)
##[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `each` argument in the `rep` command:

```
rep(1:2, each = 10)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

My favorite non-`na.locf` way:

```
c(NA, n[!is.na(n)])[cumsum(!is.na(n)) + 1]
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

If there are `NA`s before the first value, they will stay. But if you know there are no `NA`s at the beginning of the vector it's just:

```
not.na <- !is.na(n)
n[not.na][cumsum(not.na)]
```